# If I've got only two days for the gym, should they be consecutive or not for best results?

Tags: gym, exercise-frequency

If I've got only two days for the gym per week, should they be consecutive or not for best results?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your muscles require exercise followed by rest and recovery in order to promote muscle growth. Too long *or* too short of a recovery period and they won't adapt (i.e. get bigger).

Going only two days a week to the gym, the best bang for your buck would be a full-body workout on two non-consecutive days minimizing the rest time between both workouts. Think Monday and Thursday, Wednesday and Sunday, etc.

Comment: isn't 24 hours of rest enough? rarely ever rested more than that..

Comment: @Avdol -- Absolutely. 24h is usually more than enough for someone who goes to the gym regularly. This question just asked about 2x workouts per week so you'd have to have more than 24h rest in between workouts at some point (e.g. If you went Mon and Tues (24h rest between) you'd have 144h rest between Tues and the following Monday).

Comment: So kinda 2,3 days betwixt workouts, am I correct buddy?

Comment: Exactly, and if you can fit in a third day at some point you'd do 1 and 2 days between workouts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Take care.